# Another default MapRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, maproute

In my website, I have the following default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I access the Index page from the Home controller, I get the following address:

http://localhost/MyWebsite/

Everything is okay, however, I would like to add another default route for the following Controller and Page:

http://localhost/MyWebsite/Profile/Index/8

For the link above, **I would like to have the following route**:

http://localhost/MyWebsite/Profile/8

Without showing the "Index" page name.

How is it possible?

Comment: Have you considered using AttributeRouting instead of manually setting them up?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the RouteConfig, set enable to route Actions via Attribute:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

After that, add the Attribute Route above the Action name:

```
[Route("Perfil/{id}")]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    return View();
}
```